# Async/Await in Puppeteer Wait till Page Loads

Tags: javascript, php, async-await, puppeteer

Using async/await, how I do handle waiting for a page to load until reading it?

I have a long running PHP cron on a website. To get around timeouts, it breaks the problem up in chunks, redirects the browser to the next step, and finally ends with `die('Done');` This means the final html of the page looks something like this.

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>Done</body>
</html>
```

So with Puppeteer, I'm trying to hit that long running script and just let it go until I get 'Done' to close out my test.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args:['--no-sandbox']});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com/Test/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'}); //dev
  //await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  // Eventually if script runs, will get run in PHP die('Done') so select text and quit.
  // await page.waitForNavigation();
  let element = await page.$("body").catch(() => {});
  let text = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, element).catch(() => {});

  if (text == 'Done') {
    await browser.close();
  }
})();
```

Right now on a test site that just does redirects, not data processing, it works and closes. On the page that actually processes data all that get's me is the values of both `element` and `text` are undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could add an id to an element like `<div id="done">Done!</div>` then you could try using the [page.waitForSelector()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) method like `await page.waitForSelector('#done')`.

First modify the PHP slightly because it isn't emitting valid HTML in the first place. Note that these waits do timeout, so disable the timeout. Finally, switch to `text.includes` for the check because the value of text may have Whitespace around it that makes it evaluate to false.

Poster's final code:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args:['--no-sandbox']});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://example.com/Test/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

  // Eventually if script runs, will get run in PHP die('Done') so select text and quit.
  await page.waitForSelector('#done', {timeout: 0});
  let element = await page.$("body").catch(() => {});
  let text = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, element).catch(() => {});

  if (text.includes("Done")) {
    await browser.close();
  }
})();
```

Comment: Yeah as I was looking at it, this is probably actually more of a flaw in the PHP. The Original Programmer formed the HTML in a variable and then just did `die($html)` which apparently is rendering nothing in the head and the body tag doesn't get closed, so I think I need to fix that, add a specific selector and we're good.